# How to create an Adjacency and a Degree matrix from OSMNX retrieved data?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am trying to create an [Adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) and a [Degree matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_matrix) from the data retrieved from the OSMNX package.
For example, I would like to create those matrices with data of the following road network:

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(37.79, 37.78, -122.41, -122.43, network_type='drive')
# Get nodes and edges
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G)
```

Could someone give me a hint on how to do this with these outputs?

Answer (score 2):

In order to create an Adjacency matrix, you can use networkx ([Docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html?highlight=adjacency_matrix#networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix)):

```
nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
```